# where should i put Remove query strings from static resources code in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have tried many times to modify that code below which I have found here in StackOverflow but without benefit.

```
function rm_query_string( $src ) {   

    $parts = explode( '?ver', $src );

    return $parts[0];
}

if ( !is_admin() ) {

    add_filter( 'script_loader_src', 'rm_query_string', 15, 1 );

    add_filter( 'style_loader_src', 'rm_query_string', 15, 1 );
}
```

Where should I put the code on the top of `function.php` of the end?

and this is the result 
https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/efmSZn/https://www.shofnow.com/
and this is the site if you want to check the source 
https://www.shofnow.com/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eulec.png)

as you can see most of the issue in images

P.S: I don't want any plugins

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the code you provided at the end of `functions.php` file. Be sure, that there isn't `?>` closing php tag. If, it is than put your code before closing tag, like:

```
//your code
?>
```

Also, that code doesn't removing `query strings` from your image urls.